# TreeViewItem not updating with bound ItemsSource, ObservableCollection, and INotifyPropertyChanged

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml

I know this question has been asked a lot but even after trying all of the different answers I still can't get this to work for me. The object I'm trying to bind to is updating correctly in the code behind so the only thing that isn't working is the children of the TreeViewItem updating when the ItemsSource is changed.

It seems that I have everything set up correctly but maybe there is something about how I am tying things together that is making this not work. I am using C# .NET 4.5 WPF project in VS 2015 in Windows 7. I am binding to a static classes' static property that has only a get method to a TreeViewItem's ItemsSource and setting DisplayMemberPath.

XAML:

```
<!-- Menu tree -->
        <TreeView Grid.Column="0"
                  x:Name="menutree"
                  Background="Transparent"
                  BorderThickness="0">
            <!-- Profiles TVI -->
            <TreeViewItem Header="{x:Static loc:Resources.profiles}"
                          IsExpanded="True">
                <!-- Color profile TVI -->
                <TreeViewItem x:Name="colorTvi"
                              Header="{x:Static loc:Resources.colorProfiles}"
                              MouseRightButtonDown="colorTvi_MouseRightButtonDown"
                              DisplayMemberPath="Name"
                              ItemsSource="{Binding Source={x:Static local:Shared.ColorProfiles}, Mode=OneWay}" />
                 <TreeViewItem ...
```

Class / Properties being bound to:

```
public static class Shared
{
    #region Getter / Setter

    // Notify property changed
    public static NotifyChanged Notify { get; set; } = new NotifyChanged();

    // All profiles that have been created
    public static List<Profile> Profiles
    {
        get { return _Profiles; }
        set
        {
            // Set profile
            _Profiles = value;
            Notify.OnPropertyChanged(nameof(Profiles));
            Notify.OnPropertyChanged(nameof(ColorProfiles));
        }
    }
    private static List<Profile> _Profiles = new List<Profile>();

    // Color profiles
    public static ObservableCollection<ColorProfile> ColorProfiles
    {
        get
        {
            return new ObservableCollection<ColorProfile>(
                Profiles?.Where(m => m.GetType() == typeof(ColorProfile))?.Cast<ColorProfile>()?.ToList() ??
                new List<ColorProfile>());
        }
    }

    #endregion
}
```

The NotifyChanged class:

```
// Property changed class
public class NotifyChanged : INotifyPropertyChanged
{

    // Property changed event
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    // Notify property changed
    public void OnPropertyChanged(string name)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(name));
    }

}
```

I would like to get this to work without having to call Refresh() in code behind. I have tried binding to Shared.Profiles directly but that doesn't help any. ColorProfile is a base class that inherits from Profile.

Hopefully there's some stupid, simple thing I'm missing. Thanks in advance for the help.

UPDATE :

On further inspection it actually looks like the ItemsSource isn't even updating. During debugging I can see in the control's property explorer that the ItemsSource is bound to an ObservableCollection but the ItemsSource is not reflecting the changes made to the list. If I manually bind in the code behind then it works.

Comment: Usually issues like this are due to the repaint event not getting called.  The simple solution is just set ItemSource to null and then back to actual source.

Comment: I can do that if I have do. That's pretty much how I've always got it to work in the past but it would be nice to get this to work without any extra code behind

Answer (score 0):

Notify is the one shouting PropertyChanged, on itself.

No one is binded to Notify so no one is updating.

The one who needs to implement INotifyPropertyChanged, or inherit from NotifyChanged is Shared.

Comment: I wish I could! Unfortunately static classes cannot inherit from either.

Comment: I understand. so instead you could have Shared inherit DependencyObject, and have all your properties as DependencyProperties.